# please help me NNAPI analysis

Tags: android, arm, kernel, hal, nnapi

I'm studying android platform, especially nnapi.

I found out Arm nn driver processes requests from application through NNAPI.

I was trying to figure out the flow of the function in the code base, and I am currently facing a problem that cannot be solved.

I wonder if the arm nn driver controls hardware directly as a kind of kernel device driver or is simply a library and there is a separate kernel code that handles it.

If the latter, can you tell me where the kernel code starts?

Answer (score 0):

pleaseletmeknow,

Can you provide more details about what you're trying to achieve and the problems you're encountering?

You should not need to know the underlying architecture of the drivers to be able to use them.

If you are curious about Arm NN lib, you can look in their open source repository at https://github.com/ARM-software/armnn. Note that it's not the same as the NNAPI Arm driver but may be of interest to you.

Comment: I suggest you look at this Arm video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNwl5RRkIRE. While PyTorch specific, it contains info about how the Arm NNAPI driver works. It also shows some performance comparison for int8 and fp32. It would have been great if they had also compared fp16, which can often be a good choice.